# snap draggable slide to next or previous slide position

Tags: jquery

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/idoangel/fw1pcq8b/6/). I want the slider to be draggable, but when you even move one item slightly to each side, it should complete a whole step and snap to the position of its precious/next slide. like [here](http://outofsite.co.il/buddhism/).

I tried playing around with .draggable() but didn't really get anywhere.

This is the code so far:

```
    <div class="ido">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="sliderin">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://thegreenbox.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/0021-1.jpg">
          <div class="button">
            <span>i</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                <p>text text text</p>
                <div class="button-close">
                  x
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://thegreenbox.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/0021-1.jpg">
          <div class="button">
            <span>i</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                <p>text text text</p>
                <div class="button-close">
                  x
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://thegreenbox.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/0021-1.jpg">
          <div class="button">
            <span>i</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                <p>text text text</p>
                <div class="button-close">
                  x
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://thegreenbox.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/0021-1.jpg">
          <div class="button">
            <span>i</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                <p>text text text</p>
                <div class="button-close">
                  x
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://thegreenbox.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/0021-1.jpg">
          <div class="button">
            <span>i</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                <p>text text text</p>
                <div class="button-close">
                  x
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://thegreenbox.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/0021-1.jpg">
          <div class="button">
            <span>i</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                <p>text text text</p>
                <div class="button-close">
                  x
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://thegreenbox.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/0021-1.jpg">
          <div class="button">
            <span>i</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                <p>text text text</p>
                <div class="button-close">
                  x
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://thegreenbox.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/0021-1.jpg">
          <div class="button">
            <span>i</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                <p>text2 text2 text2</p>
                <div class="button-close">
                  x
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://thegreenbox.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/0021-1.jpg">
          <div class="button">
            <span>i</span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                <p>text3 text3 text3</p>
                <div class="button-close">
                  x
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="idopagination">
    <span class="nexter"><img src="https://thegreenbox.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/leftarrow.png"></span>
    <span class="prever"><img src="https://thegreenbox.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/rightarrow.png"></span>
  </div>
</div>


.ido {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.idopagination {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 60px;
}

.idopagination span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nexter {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.prever {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.prever img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.item .image {
  width: 90%;
  float: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.button:hover,
.button-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content {
  height: 350px !important;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.button-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.sliderin {
  position: absolute;
}

  // MODAL //

  $(function() {
    $(".modal-content").draggable();
  });

  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .find(".modal")
      .fadeToggle("200");
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .find(".modal-content")
      .fadeToggle("200");
  });

  $(".button-close").click(function() {
    $(this)
      .closest(".modal")
      .fadeToggle("200");
    $(this)
      .closest(".modal-content")
      .fadeToggle("200");
  });

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      $(".modal").fadeOut("200");
      $(".modal-content").fadeOut("200");
    }
  });

  // SLIDER //

  var sliderwidth = $(".slider").width();

  if (sliderwidth > 869) {
    var itemwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10) / 3;
    $(".slider .sliderin .item").css("width", itemwidth);
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10) * 3;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10) * 6;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos, 10) - 1;
  } else if (sliderwidth < 870 && sliderwidth > 579) {
    var itemwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10) / 2;
    $(".slider .sliderin .item").css("width", itemwidth);
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10) * 4.5;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10) * 7;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos - itemwidth - 1);
  } else {
    $(".slider .sliderin .item").css("width", sliderwidth);
    var itemwidth = sliderwidth;
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10) * 9;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10) * 8;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos, 10) - 1;
  }

  var leftedge = parseInt(-1);

  $(".slider .sliderin").css({
    width: sliderinwidth,
    left: -firstpos
  });

  var sliderheight = $(".slider .sliderin .item").height();
  $(".slider").css("height", sliderheight);

  function modifyWidth() {
    var sliderwidth = $(".slider").width();

    if (sliderwidth > 869) {
      var itemwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10) / 3;
      $(".slider .sliderin .item").css("width", itemwidth);
      var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10) * 3;
      var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10) * 6;
      var endpos = parseInt(firstpos, 10) - 1;
    } else if (sliderwidth < 870 && sliderwidth > 579) {
      var itemwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10) / 2;
      $(".slider .sliderin .item").css("width", itemwidth);
      var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10) * 4.5;
      var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10) * 7;
      var endpos = parseInt(firstpos - itemwidth - 1);
    } else {
      $(".slider .sliderin .item").css("width", sliderwidth);
      var itemwidth = sliderwidth;
      var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10) * 9;
      var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10) * 8;
      var endpos = parseInt(firstpos, 10) - 1;
    }

    var leftedge = parseInt(-1);

    $(".slider .sliderin").css({
      width: sliderinwidth,
      left: -firstpos
    });

    var sliderheight = $(".slider .sliderin .item").height();
    $(".slider").css("height", sliderheight);
  }

  $(".idopagination .nexter").click(function() {
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .find(".sliderin")
      .animate({
        left: "+=" + itemwidth
      }, "slow", function() {
        var posn = $(this).position();
        if (posn.left > leftedge) {
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".nexter")
            .css("pointer-events", "none");
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".nexter img")
            .css("filter", "grayscale(100%)");
        } else {
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".nexter")
            .css("pointer-events", "initial");
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".nexter img")
            .css("filter", "none");
        }
        if (posn.left < -endpos) {
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".prever")
            .css("pointer-events", "none");
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".prever img")
            .css("filter", "grayscale(100%)");
        } else {
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".prever")
            .css("pointer-events", "initial");
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".prever img")
            .css("filter", "none");
        }
      });
  });

  $(".idopagination .prever").click(function() {
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .find(".sliderin")
      .animate({
        left: "-=" + itemwidth
      }, "slow", function() {
        var posp = $(this).position();
        if (posp.left > leftedge) {
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".nexter")
            .css("pointer-events", "none");
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".nexter img")
            .css("filter", "grayscale(100%)");
        } else {
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".nexter")
            .css("pointer-events", "initial");
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".nexter img")
            .css("filter", "none");
        }
        if (posp.left < -endpos) {
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".prever")
            .css("pointer-events", "none");
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".prever img")
            .css("filter", "grayscale(100%)");
        } else {
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".prever")
            .css("pointer-events", "initial");
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .parent()
            .find(".prever img")
            .css("filter", "none");
        }
      });
  });

  // END //

  $(window).resize(function() {
    modifyWidth();
  });
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

Comment: yea, i tried. the only option i could think of is grid, but:
1. setting the grid to the width of the item make it unmovable
2. i want that even if you drag the slider 5 pixels to a direction, that it will complete the movement of the entire step (move an entire item in the direction of that slight movement)

Answer (score 0):

I'm slowly getting there:

```
    var start,stop;

    $(".sliderin").draggable({
        axis: "x",
        start: function(event, ui) {
            start = ui.position.left;
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            stop = ui.position.left;
            if (start < stop) {
            $(".sliderin").animate({
            left: "+=" + itemwidth
          }, "slow")
            }
            else {
            $(".sliderin").animate({
            left: "-=" + itemwidth
          }, "slow")
            }
    }
});
```

just need to figure out how to complete the movement to the itemwidth, and not make it itemwidth, because the movement is calculated after stopping the drap which already made some distance.

Answer (score 0):

got it :)

1. i had to enter parseInt before each var in the equation.
2. i have to calclate the distance from start point to end point differently when moving right or moving left: for right it was (stop-start), for left it was (start-stop).
3. once i had that distance calculated, i could animate the itemwidth-distance as the remaining animation.

here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/idoangel/z6t1odn2/1/

and here's the code to add to the original:

```
 var start, stop;

  $(".sliderin").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      start = ui.position.left;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      stop = ui.position.left;
      var distancer = parseInt(stop, 10) - parseInt(start, 10);
      var distancel = parseInt(start, 10) - parseInt(stop, 10);
      var whatsleftr = parseInt(itemwidth, 10) - parseInt(distancer, 10);
      var whatsleftl = parseInt(itemwidth, 10) - parseInt(distancel, 10);
      if (start < stop) {
        $(".sliderin").animate({
          left: "+=" + whatsleftr
        }, "slow")
      } else {
        $(".sliderin").animate({
          left: "-=" + whatsleftl
        }, "slow")
      }
    }
  });
```